# Java Email message Parser?

Tags: java, parsing, email, email-parsing

Is anyone familiar with a Java library that helps with parsing the fields (date, subject, from, to) of the email below?

```
Message-ID: <19815303.1075861029555.JavaMail.ss@kk>
Date: Wed, 6 Mar 2010 12:32:20 -0800 (PST)
From: someone@someotherplace.com
To: someone@someplace.com
Subject: some subject
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-From: one, some <some.one@someotherplace.com>
X-To: one
X-cc: 
X-bcc: 
X-Folder: Bob\Inbox
X-Origin: Bob-R
X-FileName: rbob (Non-Privileged).pst


some message
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) is an oracle library that provides mail services and mail related services (like parsing conventional & MIME messages) in the javax.mail package.  Additionally Apache has a [Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) library for mail handling.

In the JavaMail api, a simple way to parse a string containing an email message (which may or may not be explicitly MIME) would be as follows

```
String content = ...
Session s = Session.getInstance(new Properties());
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(s, is);
```

and parsing the headers could be done like this

```
message.getAllHeaderLines();
for (Enumeration<Header> e = message.getAllHeaders(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
    Header h = e.nextElement();
    h.getName();
    h.getValue();
}
```

Comment: But how do I parse the "From:" header, and separate between the names and the email addresses

Comment: @HendyIrawan there is a getFrom() method on the Message class.  It returns an Address[] type, and the members of that array can typically be cast to an InternetAddress type if you're dealing with actual email messages.  This class has methods for getting the name and email portions of an RFC822 compliant address.

Comment: this works great ! however, how can i read an email thread which has multiple emails ? i tried the approach above but it only reads the first email. also, how can i extract just the message body ?

Comment: You would need to parse each one of the messages and create your own in-memory structure that represents the conversation thread.  The thread can generally be reconstructed by looking at the 'In-Reply-To:' header of a given message, which will contain the Message-ID: header of the email to which it was a response.

Comment: For the rest, I suggest you try doing some experimentation and if you get stuck you can come back and either find a more relevant question and answer, or ask a question of your own.

Answer (score 10):

I have had problems with JavaMail (it fails to parse some email messages that it should).

I have had much better results with [**Mime4J**](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/index.html).

Comment: - Have you noticed it failing for mime messages generated with any specific application or platform?

Comment: @AdamGent. There are quite a few [system properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html) that you have to set in order to get JavaMail's mime parser to be a bit more 'relaxed'. Otherwise it acts in 'strict mode'.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest you use [email-mime-parser](https://github.com/ram-sharma-6453/email-mime-parser),

Following sample code gives you all the relevant info you need:

```
ContentHandler contentHandler = new CustomContentHandler();

MimeConfig mime4jParserConfig = new MimeConfig();
BodyDescriptorBuilder bodyDescriptorBuilder = new DefaultBodyDescriptorBuilder();
MimeStreamParser mime4jParser = new MimeStreamParser(mime4jParserConfig,DecodeMonitor.SILENT,bodyDescriptorBuilder);
mime4jParser.setContentDecoding(true);
mime4jParser.setContentHandler(contentHandler);

InputStream mailIn = 'Provide email mime stream here';
mime4jParser.parse(mailIn);

Email email = ((CustomContentHandler) contentHandler).getEmail();

List<Attachment> attachments =  email.getAttachments();

Attachment calendar = email.getCalendarBody();
Attachment htmlBody = email.getHTMLEmailBody();
Attachment plainText = email.getPlainTextEmailBody();

String to = email.getToEmailHeaderValue();
String cc = email.getCCEmailHeaderValue();
String from = email.getFromEmailHeaderValue();
```

Comment: This is based on Mime4j

Comment: Yes, It is based on Mime4j