# Parse email string to data structure in Clojure

Tags: email, clojure

I'm looking for a way to take an email message in plain text and parse it into something nicer for use in a Clojure project. The resulting data structure should allow me to quickly get the sender, subject, body and attachments.

There is a similar question to this but in Java:

[Java Email message Parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444660/java-email-message-parser)

Most libraries I found only support email sending and not necessarily parsing.

Comment: use javax.mail, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444660/java-email-message-parser is answer.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do that in a proper answer?

Comment: If you already have an example of how to do it in Java, my first instinct would be to use Java interop to do the parsing and then `clojure.core/bean` to turn it into a Clojure structure.

Answer (score 4):

Since nobody answered, maybe I should. Here is a very simple example of loading an email file and printing out the `from` field (first address).

```
(ns something.views.welcome
  (:use [noir.core :only [defpage]]
        [clojure.contrib.java-utils]
        [clojure.java.io :only [input-stream]])
(:import 
    (javax.mail Session)
    (javax.mail.internet MimeMessage)
))


(def session
    (Session/getDefaultInstance 
    (as-properties [["mail.store.protocol" "imaps"]])))


(def email "email.txt")

(defn get-message [filename]
    (bean (MimeMessage. session (input-stream filename))))

(defn get-from [message]
    (.toString (first (:from message))))



(println (get-from (get-message email)))
```