# AWS SES - incoming email saving attachment to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have the following use case:

- Once and incoming email with attachment is received (SES)
- Invoke a lambda function to Extract that email's attachment only and save to S3

I've looked at SES SDK (nodejs) and wasn't successful in finding an API that could help with this.

Is this supported out-of-the-box using SES SDK (nodejs, java)? Or one has to read the entire message and then figure out the attachment portion?

Has anyone with similar requirements been able to implement this?

Comment: Did you get this figured out? Got the same exact need here. Hopefully you didn't end up parsing the raw email line by line

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported by the SES sdk. You will have to parse the raw MIME format and extract the file.
Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723809/aws-ses-s3-process-inbound-email) on how you can try that with Lambda