# Extract email attachment from SES into S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to extract an email attachment and save that attachment into an S3 bucket. I have configured SES to intercept my incoming emails.

I am guessing I need to create a SES rule which would have an action to trigger a Lambda function that extracts the email attachment and stores it to S3. I am not sure how to write this Lambda function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS SES S3 process inbound email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723809/aws-ses-s3-process-inbound-email)